# cleaner syntax for IF /VLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

It happens sometimes that I need to test the return value of a function and decide whether to keep or modify it. When you do this in a single cell, it can lead to two calls to that function - for example

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(value, table, colNum, FALSE)="Not Affiliated", "Something", VLOOKUP(value, table, colNum, FALSE))
```

Is it possible to do this in a way that doesn't involve two calls to `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: Does it all have to be in the same cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following (works in Excel - I think it should work in GS):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(val, range, col, FALSE), "Not Affiliated", "Something")
```

This is not exactly what you asked, since it will not replicate the behavior of your example if the lookup returns `Not Affiliated with any company`. Your code would skip that, my code would return `Something with any company`.